# jquery : wait until all ajax calls finish then continue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wait

I have some ajax calls in my document.ready()

like :

```
for (j=1; j <= 7; j++){
  (function(index) {
    $.getJSON('my.php', {id:index}, 
      function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index2, array){
         ........
         });  
      });
    })(j)
} 

//DO NOT CONTINUE UNTIL FINISH AJAX CALLS   

 ........
MORE JQUERY CODE
```

How can i force it to wait and not continue until we get all the call backs from the ajax requests ?

Comment: See my other answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11315571/49885, ajaxStop is what you want, its been built in since jquery 1.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I do not like any answer at all, the best way (since Jquery 1.5+) is to use Deferred objects, those are objects to manipulate async calls, you can solve :

```
$.when($.ajax("/page1.php"), $.ajax("/page2.php"))
  .then(myFunc, myFailure);
```

This way myFunc executes after the 2 ajax calls are made, and myFailure if either one has an error.

You can read more about it in the jquery official documentation:[`JQuery Deferred Object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

I write this solution if anyone sees this post it may be helpful.

Sorry my english :P

Comment: Whatever you call them - deferred objects, promises, etc. - those seem like a much better solution than parallel loops to me

Answer (score 6):

First off, you might want to consider doing the startup code in a single call.
Second: Instead of waiting just call another function call. for the above code it should look something like:

```
for (j=1; j <= 7; j++){
  (function(index) {
    $.getJSON('my.php', {id:index}, 
      function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index2, array){
         ........
         }); 

         if (j === 7) {
            initDoneDoMoreStuff()
         }
      });
    })(j)
}
```

or trigger:

```
for (j=1; j <= 7; j++){
  (function(index) {
    $.getJSON('my.php', {id:index}, 
      function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(index2, array){
         ........
         }); 

         if (j === 7) {
            $(document).trigger("initdone");
         }
      });
    })(j)
}

$(document).bind("initdone", function() {....});
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked beautifully for me. (the triggering initdone)

Comment: I tried async: false and still had issues. The solution to call the submitting function within ajax was perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It wasn´t easy for me to do it, but maybe you find my code useful. It´s a process to submit all forms in the dom and after all of them are stored, redirect the user to another page.

```
formulario = $('form');
formulariolongitud = formulario.length;
i = 0;

formulario.each(function(index, value) {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        async: false,//not sure i
        success: function() {
            i++; 

            if(i === formulario.length) {//this is the last one to submit
                window.location.replace(whatever);
            }
        } 
    });                         
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use sucess (ie a callback function of ajax jquery) like below :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
 dataType: 'json',
 data: data,
 success: function(data){
 //Write your code here.
    }
});
```

You can get documentation of ajax below -

[ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: how can i use it in my code ?

Comment: @Haim Evgi: Move the code you have after the call and you want to execute after the call finished inside the callback.

Comment: I have edited my code as per your requirement. You can use ajax instead of getjson as described above.

Comment: thank you very much , but i use @shay solution

Comment: I used a variant of this for some post backs to a cgi handler. JQuery provides another function, $.post, which also allows you to call a function on success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with something like if (j == 7) is the situation when the 7th request is very very fast, and even one of the others is slow. Even though you have queued it up last, it might not be the last to complete.

This answer seems to work for all conditions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3709809/813154