# JavaScript greater than not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JavaScript snippet:

```
function verifyFrnds(){
    var boxes=$(".matchFrnds:checked").length;
    //alert(boxes); its value is 50 when you do alert
    var call=1;
    $(".matchFrnds").each(function(index){

        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            call++;
            var sendData= $(this).val();

            $.post('SOME PHP Page',{sendData:sendData},function(data){      
                //window.location.reload();
            });

            //alert(call); value is 1
            // 1 >=50 should be false but all the time the condition gets true
            if(call >= boxes)
            {
                window.location.reload();
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

The question is self explanatory. The conditions gets true even when it is not. Not sure if it is due to that it is not treating them as numbers and strings may be, but all the time the condition gets true.

Comment: have you check the boxes values and call variables values? just add alert before alert(cal); and alert(boxes);

Comment: You don't touch the unchecked items in your loop, why have the separate test anyway? Just loop over `$(".matchFrnds:checked").each()`

Comment: `alert(boxes)`? Please keep us informed.

Comment: 1) [Don't use `alert()` for debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cdndevs/archive/2011/05/26/console-log-say-goodbye-to-javascript-alerts-for-debugging.aspx) and 2) [there's nothing immediately wrong with what you've posted](http://jsfiddle.net/YYVh3/). Based on the commented out reload line in the Ajax call I'd guess there's something there that makes you think the later condition is triggered when it actually is not, but hard to say without seeing a complete example.

Comment: Being an "optimization freak" I wouldn't do 50 separate XHR requests but one request for all matching condition (checked) and based on the rules on the server send the needed callback to the client.

Comment: @Terror.Blade yes and I mentioned in the commpents

Comment: @Juhana anything related to typecasting may be java is considering them as string

Comment: but have you checked the value of boxes . that was my concern

Comment: @Terror.Blade yes and it was 50

Comment: @wared 50 was the alert

Comment: Why do you think the condition is true, then?

Comment: `alert(call+' '+(typeof call)+' '+boxes+' '+(typeof boxes)+' '+(call>=boxes));`, paste the output in a comment.

Comment: @Juhana may be something related to strings,

Comment: @user1765876 No, I mean why do you say that the line `if(call >= boxes)` is "always true"? How have you confirmed that? Do you have an alert inside the if as well? Because what you've posted here, there's only a reload command there; you can't say that the condition is "always true" just because the page is reloaded at some point.

Comment: @wared it is 2 32 false

Comment: So, this is the expected result right?

Comment: @wared Yes but the page reloads

Comment: @Juhana You got it right, " the condition is "always true" just because the page is reloaded at some point" well noted

Comment: @user1765876 If the condition is always `true`, how did you alert such a result?

Comment: Nice that I was downvoted for that !

Comment: @wared If the condition is true or false the window.location.reload() gets executed

Comment: @qdev didn't get your point here

Comment: @user1765876 Sure, so, how `2 32 false` is possible? Ok, forget it... :)

Comment: @wared if it is false then why the page reloads regardless of the false condition?

Comment: Without a live example we will argue here over this or that and maybe the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It reloads because *at some point* the condition is true. The logic is way off --- `boxes` is the number of checked checkboxes, and you loop through all checked checkboxes, so of course the condition is true for the last checkbox (or actually already for the next to last because the count starts from 2), regardless of how many checkboxes are checked.

Comment: @Juhana I loop through all check boxes but it gets true before it loop through all, because you can see the AJAX request I made when the checkbox is checked..nad it insert somevalue in DB for each checkbox in the DB, so if the page reloads then it should insert value after processing for all checked boxes /

Comment: Ajax requests are *asynchronous*. The reload happens before all/any of them have time to complete, even if the reload is triggered by the last loop iteration. See e.g. [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952387/jquery-wait-until-all-ajax-calls-finish-then-continue) (tl;dr: put the counter in the Ajax callback.)

Comment: @Juhana still not getting it, when, then are defered in jquery

Answer (score 0):

I'm missing some context but try this:

```
function verifyFrnds() { 

    var boxes = $(".matchFrnds:checked").length;

    $(".matchFrnds:checked").each(function(index) {

        var sendData= $(this).val();
        $.post('SOME PHP Page',{sendData:sendData},function(data){      
            //window.location.reload();
        });

        if(index >= boxes-1) {
            window.location.reload();
            return false;
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score -1):

use below code

```
if(parseInt(call) >= parseInt(boxes))
            {
                window.location.reload();
            }
```

Comment: I am trying in a minute

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't make any sense at all. First of all, the variables are initialized as integers so converting them from integer to integer does nothing. Secondly, even if they would change into strings by some code that hasn't been shown to us, JavaScript implicitly converts strings to integers for comparison, i.e. `"1" >= "50" === false`.

Comment: as you see in code op defined call=1; and after that he is doing call++; still user saying that call value is 1 so that means call is not geting added if that converted to int then call value must be 2 but as it is not happening i thought user might give shot to convert into int forcefully.

Comment: @Terror.Blade If the condition is true or false the window.location.reload() gets executed

Comment: It will work without "=" in if condition like this    if(parseInt(call) >parseInt(boxes))

Answer (score -1):

Doesn't `window.location.reload()` from your post callback resets your checkboxes thus none being checked ?

1 will always be greater than 0

Of course that this depends on how the form is initialized in HTML, but we don't know this from your example.

Maybe if you present to us a more detailed explanation of what you have and what you want to do, we can present you a better solution.

Comment: If the page is reloaded the script execution is stopped as well. Even if the checkboxes are reset the value of variable `boxes` doesn't automatically change.

Comment: @Juhana - we also don't know what triggers the JS execution either, not explained. Could be on document ready. And you're wrong. If the page reloads, and no checkbox is checked and the function is called again, it will be reinitialized with 0.

Comment: All the variables are inside the same function. Execution time doesn't matter.

Comment: If the function is called again, the `if` is never encountered because for every checkbox `if($(this).is(':checked')` is false.

Comment: the boxes would be anyway zero as stated, but you're correct, it will not get to the check anymore